# using nodemon together with gulp doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gulp

I used gulp with broswersync, to watch any front end changes. But in the same time I'm using node.js so I need nodemon to restart server if I changed anything on the server side. Not sure I'm doing it right, below is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
    var reload      = browserSync.reload;
    var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

    gulp.task('serve', function() {

        browserSync.init({
            server: "./public"
        });

        gulp.watch(['./public/*.html', './public/js/*.js']).on('change', reload);
    });

    gulp.task('sass', function () {
      return gulp.src('./public/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
    });

    gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
      gulp.watch('./public/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
    });

    // our gulp-nodemon task
    gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
        var started = false;
        return nodemon({
            script: './bin/www',
            ext: 'js',
            ignore: ['public/*'],
            env: {
                'NODE_ENV': 'development',
                'DEBUG': 'appname:*'
         }
        }).on('start', function () {
            if (!started) {
                cb();
                started = true;
            }
        })
        .on('crash', function() {
            console.log('nodemon.crash');
        })
        .on('restart', function() {
            console.log('nodemon.restart');
        })
        .once('quit', function () {
            process.exit();
        });
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['serve','sass','sass:watch','nodemon']);
```

I run `gulp` but it has error of

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
```

Comment: pretty much what the error says.  port 3000 is in use.  run this in your terminal to see what's running on port 3000: `lsof -i :3000`

Comment: 'lsof' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: use sudo apt-get install lsof to install it. Another command you can run is ps -fea | grep node and kill the process with kill -9 <pid>.